# how to export powershel result to csv

Tags: powershell, foreach, export-csv

I want to export what I already filtered in ForEach-Object. The problem is  that I can't export the filtered data.

I tried the following:
`$getTapes.rows | Export-Csv C:\\123\\123456.txt` but this has exported all the information without filter.

```
$getTapes = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -ContentType $content -Uri $Uri -Headers @{'Authorization' = $Authorization}
$today = Get-Date
$getTapes.rows | ForEach-Object {
    $tape = $_;    
    if ( $tape.custom_fields.Ueberschreibschutz.value -ge $today ) {
        Write-Host "Treffer ID=" $tape.asset_tag " Name=" $tape.name " SNR=" $tape.serial " Mediensatz=" $tape.custom_fields.Mediensatz.value
    }
}
$getTapes.rows |export-Csv C:\\123\\123456.txt
```

I expect:

```
Treffer ID= 1  Name= 12  SNR= 12345  Mediensatz= M 
Treffer ID= 2  Name= 32  SNR= 54321  Mediensatz= W
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use Write-Host to collect data. That's only to output pixels on the screen. Instead you should create a custom object you can use as you want later on ... like this:

```
    $Result = $getTapes.rows | ForEach-Object { 
    if ( $_.custom_fields.Ueberschreibschutz.value -ge $today ) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            TrefferID  = $_.asset_tag
            Name       = $_.name
            SNR        = $_.serial
            Mediensatz = $_.custom_fields.Mediensatz.value
        }
    }
}

$Result | Export-Csv -Path C:\123\123456.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

`Write-host` do nothing except it shows you the result in the console, so it will not modify or delete the things you don't want in `$getTapes.rows`.
Instead you can define a variable `$result` and iterate over the `$getTapes.rows` using `Foreach-Object`, and add the result if it meets your if condition.

Try this:

```
$getTapes = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -ContentType $content -Uri $Uri -Headers @{'Authorization' = $Authorization}
$today = Get-Date
$getTapes.rows | ForEach-Object -begin {$result = "" } {
    $tape = $_;    
    if ( $tape.custom_fields.Ueberschreibschutz.value -ge $today ) {
        $result += "Treffer ID= $($tape.asset_tag) Name= $($tape.name) SNR= $($tape.serial) Mediensatz= $($tape.custom_fields.Mediensatz.value)`n"
    }
} -end {$result | export-Csv C:\123\123456.txt}
```